# Как получить уникальные значения из массива объектов класса?

Tags: python

Есть массив объектов `Card`. В c# я могу сделать так

```
var lst = new List<Card>();
var rez = lst.DistinctBy(x=>x.suit).ToList();
```

То есть брать уникальные значения. Как сделать тоже самое в питон?

```
class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, rank, suit, dop):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.dop = dop

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.rank == other.rank and self.suit == other.suit

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.rank < other.rank
```

Answer (score 0):

Действия:

- Есть список из `Card`: `lst = [<Card>, <Card>, ...]`
- Создание словаря, где ключом будет значение поля `suit`, а значением `Card`
- Получение значений словаря

Пример:

```
rez = {x.suit: x for x in lst}.values()
```

Метод `.values()` вернет не список (`list`), а объект `dict_values` (его можно итерировать), а чтобы получить список:

```
rez = list({x.suit: x for x in lst}.values())
```